# MacOS - How to use terminal with 'set -o emacs'?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

I like to do a lot of work in a shell and I usually setup the shell to use emacs keybindings.   On linux, it's just a quick 'set -o emacs' and I'm good to go.   However, on MacOS, the solution eludes me.  (To be clear, I'm not using emacs the editor, but editing shell commands).

All the ctrl keys work, ctrl-a, ctrl-f, ctrl-b, but the meta key strokes don't seem to be bound to either the option or command keys.

I've searched for a solution and I'm not the only one asking, but I don't see a solution.   I'm happy to switch to a different app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the top menu, go to Terminal -> Preferences.
2. In the Preferences window, select the *Profiles* tab
3. Select *Keyboard* from the tabs on the right-hand side of the Profiles panel.
4. Tick the "Use Option as Meta key" checkbox.

You can now use the option key for the meta key strokes.

See: [Preferences/Keyboard dialog with "Use Option as Meta key" checkbox ticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT1em.png) for a screenshot

Comment: Thanks.   I saw that but I assumed that it took control from the command key.   Hm, now I just need to bind the rest of my "emacs world" to the option key for consistency.

Comment: That's great, you can also do cmd-opt-O to toggle the Option kety between Meta/Option. But how do you make "command" become "super" in emacs -nw terminal?